# How to check and delete a symlink if it exists, using Perl?

Tags: perl

```
if (-e "$ENV{MYHOME}/link") {
    system("rm $ENV{MYHOME}/link");
}
```

This is the code being used to check if a symlink exists and remove it if it does.

I am tracking a bug where this code does not work. I have not been able to figure it out as of now, but what is happening is that this code is unable to remove the symlink, which results in a 'File exists' error down the line.

I wanted to check if there is some fundamental flaw with this technique? I also read about http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html but would like to know if the current approach is not recommended due to some reason?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use:

```
if ( -l "$ENV{MYHOME}/link" ) {
    unlink "$ENV{MYHOME}/link"
        or die "Failed to remove file $ENV{MYHOME}/link: $!\n";
}
```

If the unlink fails, it'll say why.  The `-l` asks if the target is a link.  The `-e` asks if the file exists.  If your link is to a non-existent file, it'll return false, and your code would fail to remove the link.

Comment: does `-l` check if the file is symlink or hard link? or both?

Comment: @mask8 - `-l` it returns true if the path is a symlink.  Hard linked files appear as regular files, where the only difference is their link count (the `st_nlink` from stat) is greater than one.  Directories cannot be hard linked in Linux/Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only have the permissions of the user it is running under. Is it possible that the symlink is owned by another user and not writable?

Also, there is always the possibility that $ENV{MYHOME} does not contain what you think it does...

Comment: Yes, that is one possibility I am looking into, this is possible but should not happen.

Comment: BTW, unlink is much more efficient as you are not forking another process. Also, I don't know how heavily loaded your system is or how often of an occurrence this is, but forking a system call like that opens the possibility of something like your pid table being full and not being able to fork.

Answer (score 0):

Respective operating systems have its own `errno.h`.  I would use `Errno.pm` to handle each errors.

```
use Errno;
use File::Spec;

my $dir = File::Spec->catfile($ENV{MYHOME}, 'link');

if (!unlink $dir) {
    if ($! == Errno::ENOENT) {
        die "Failed to remove '$dir'. File doesn't exist:$!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Backwards? Why ignore "real" errors and only print the one that doesn't matter.

Comment: PS - `use Errno; if ($! == Errno::ENOENT)` can also be written `if ($!{ENOENT})`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ikegami.  Real errors are locale sensitive and are not for handling.  Anyway, I didn't know the `%!` idiom. +1

Comment: I mean you should be doing `if ($! != Errno::ENOENT) { die ... }`. You're doing the opposite of what the OP wants to do.