# Cleanup Perl script should not delete a directory that is symlinked to

Tags: perl

A cleanup Perl script running periodically deletes old log files, and if the folder is empty, it deletes the folder as well. Unfortunately, there is one exception: it should not delete a directory that is symlinked to.

Comment: I don't understand. Where is the symlink and where does it point?

Comment: Can you use hard links instead of soft links?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check and delete a symlink if it exists, using Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074005/how-to-check-and-delete-a-symlink-if-it-exists-using-perl)

Comment: You can check for symlink using the `-l` [file test operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X). E.g.: `say "symlink dir" if -d $dir  && -l $dir`

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tell if there exists a symlink that directly references a dir. (Same for indirect references.)

The best you could do is check every single file on the entire file system, but even that monumental effort wouldn't be perfect. For example, it won't find symlinks on devices that aren't currently mounted, it won't find foreign symlinks to shared portions of the file system, etc.